# AUTOCOMPLETE in excel brings only the second word in sentence why?

Tags: microsoft-excel

how can I have in the drop down all the choices I have from the first letter I put?

maybe its autocomplete and also multi select?
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WqLt.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community thanks I added photo

Comment: The image is barely legible, and doesn't show what your issue is.

Comment: @spikey_richie I changed to another one. the issue is that only in the secont word after the space the autocomplete appears. and I wish when I am starting to write it will bring me options from the dropdown. thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @spikey_richie do you know anything about it?

Comment: How had you created the drop-down list? You need VBA to make it really work as you like, so not simple to do. Would you be ready to go into VBA?

Comment: Maybe you can try OFFSET function in Data Validation List option...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change the default behavior of Excel autocomplete, other than just switching it off.

In cell auto-complete seems to work from cells directly above or below the current cell being edited - but it will only auto-complete if there is only one unique match. E.g. if you have "John" and "Mary" in a list, and start typing "J" below Mary, it will offer to auto-complete "John". However, if you have "John" and "Joe", it will only offer "John" once you have type "Joh", as "J" and "Jo" still have multiple solutions.

Annoyingly, if you use a data validation drop down list, there is no auto-complete and you *cannot* even click in the list and press a letter key to jump to the list options starting with that letter.

If you opt of combo boxes (either form or active-x control), the default controls do not include auto-complete either.

Two options:

- You can code [auto-complete in VBA for a combo box control](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html)
- You can opt to search the list using cell formula, like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1711497/how-to-search-through-dropdown-list/1711530#1711530)